# I need to take unique values from one sheet in excel, total them up by unique values and place the data in another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Scenario:

I have a list of Company names associated with individual contracts all in the column labeled "Company". I need to take each unique company name, create a column on another sheet within the workbook, total up the number of times that company appears and then total up the total contract dollars. example:

Company                       Total 
Riordan & Scully Insurance        $312.70 
Riordan & Scully Insurance        $904.80

So I need the data to show up in sheet 2 like this:

Company                       Contracts        Total
Riordan & Scully Insurance        2            $1217.50

Is this possible in excel?

Comment: Try a pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely possible.

Here's a step by step:

1) Select all of your data, click "INSERT" tab, click "Pivot Table"

2) In your Pivot Table Fields window, drag Company Names from fields into the ROWS box.

3) In your Pivot Table Fields window, drag Company Names from fields into the VALUES box. Make sure that it says "Count of Company Names". If it doesn't, click the arrow next to it, click Value Field Settings, and change it appropriately.

4) In your Pivot Table Fields window, drag Contract Dollars from fields into the VALUES box. Make sure that it says "Sum of Contract Dollars".  If it doesn't, click the arrow next to it, click Value Field Settings, and change it appropriately.

You should now have a handy table that shows all of the data you were asking for.

Comment: Thanks! I am not an Excel expert, I appreciate the help

Comment: no problem! feel free to ask if you need anymore help.